# How to make clicking a loop item show a quickview popup in Elementor?

Tags: loops, popup, elementor

I have a custom loop that shows team members and their names. When the user clicks on a photo of a team member, I want to show a "quickview" popup with the team member's bio. The team member information is stored in ACF. Any advice of how I can accomplish this?